# please explain the following in veda mailchimp extension

Tags: mailchimp

Version 2.0.1 Have read all the docs I could find.

Have inherited a site where this extension appears to be syncing successfully, both ways, with single contacts. This is despite the job "mailchimp syncPushList" only reporting success about 1 time in 100. Mainly it either reports starting execution and then doesn't report result or generates errors such as "DB Error: no such table" or "failed to claim next task"

Due to various uncoordinated imports into mailchimp & civi the 2 are badly out of sync.
I would like to better understand the workings of this extension before I attempt to fix this and am hoping someone could explain the following:

I'm wondering how the cron job "mailchimp syncPushList" which I believe pushes contact from civi to mailchimp differs from action Menu>mailings>Sync CiviContacts to Mailchimp.

There's also an action Menu>Mailings>Sync Mailchimp contacts to civi.

How do the following database tables get used by the above job and actions?

tmp_mailchimp_check_c
tmp_mailchimp_push_c
tmp_mailchimp_push_m - seems to empty & fill constantly with entire MC audience

Sorry long question but hopefully short answer!